# Probabilistic domain service idempotency with HyperLogLog

Tags: service, soa, idempotent, ddd-service

I'm evaluating an approach to domain service idempotency using HyperLogLog [**HLL**].

Aim of this approach would be to provide generic way of ensuring idempotency 
without storing large amounts of useless information. Only requirement being 
tolerance for occasional duplication (send 2 email instead of one).

In my scenario every service request is a message object with toHashCode function. The algorithm looks like this:

> 1. Upon receiving **request** domain service calculates HLL[**S1**] cardinality and stores it as **C1**.
> 2. **Request** hash[**H**] is added to the **copy** of HLL[**S2**] and the cardinality is stored as **C2**.
> 3. If **C1 == C2** then request is duplicated and **S2** should be discarded.
> 4. Otherwise request will be handled and hash[**H**] will be added to HLL[**S1**].

Did anybody encounter similar solution ? (like [bloom filter](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1072133?start=0&tstart=0))
What would be the downsides of this kind of solution ?